# Overfitted vs cross-validated model performance on independent data

Tags: r, cross-validation, predictive-models

I have some trouble understanding these predictive modelling results.

- I want to compare different ways of doing latent discriminant analysis for varying sample sizes
- the example below uses two simulated datasets with 40 observations (full, reproducible simulation code is [here](https://gist.github.com/ben-aaron188/088ec300dcc2d6ff6713bead95bfe5ea#file-gistfile1-txt))
- the code below uses the two datasets: one as training set and the other as truly independent testing set
- in the analysis, we run LDA once without any cross-validation and once with leave-one-out CV on the training set

When validating these on independent data (here: testing data), I obtain results that I do not understand. The overfitted model (without CV) and the CVed model both yield the exact performance.

I would expect that the overfitted model (lda.fit_no_cv) fares worse than the CVed model (lda.fit_cv). Both obtain very different results on the training data.

Why is it that both models result in identical classification accuracy on independent data?

```
training_data = sim_data
testing_data = sim_data2

#no cv
lda.fit_no_cv = train(outcome ~ .
                   , data=training_data
                   , method="lda"
                   , trControl = trainControl(method = "none")
                   )
pred = predict(lda.fit_no_cv, training_data)
caret::confusionMatrix(pred, training_data$outcome)
#--> accuracy: 82.50

#leave-one-out cv
lda.fit_cv = train(outcome ~ .
                   , data=training_data
                   , method="lda",
                trControl = trainControl(method = "LOOCV")
                )
lda.fit_cv$results
#---> accuracy: 52.50

#test on indep data with non-cross-validated model
pred = predict(lda.fit_no_cv, testing_data)
caret::confusionMatrix(pred, testing_data$outcome)
#---> accuracy: 42.50

#test on indep data with cross-validated model
pred = predict(lda.fit_cv, testing_data)
caret::confusionMatrix(pred, testing_data$outcome)
#---> accuracy: 42.50!!
```

Comment: Seems to suggest the training model is over-fitted. Cross validation will not save you if you are building your model based on how well it does via cross validation.